# sprintf() is adding an extra variable

Tags: c++, arduino

Why is this happening?:

```
char buf[256];
char date[8];
sprintf(date,  "%d%02d%02d", Time.year(), Time.month(), Time.day());
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "{\"team\":\"%s\"}", team.c_str());
Serial.println(date);
```

output:

```
20180202{"team":"IND"}
```

it should only be: `20180202`
I don't know why `{"team":"IND"}` is getting added to the end of it.

Comment: @TheDude Check the edit

Comment: @SlakNation You MUST post the declarations, just like the compiler we don't know how much space is allocated for `date` and it appears to be too little.

Comment: @SlakNation Mind to post a [MCVE] please?

Comment: Are you sure that `date` is of size 9, not 8? If it is something like `char date[8]`, then you there is UB. (And then, in practice, such output can happen if `buf` is right after `date` in memory.)

Comment: It's interesting that you use `sprintf()` for one case (the one that overruns the buffer) and use `snprintf()` in the other case. If you has used `snprintf()` for the first case you still would have not gotten the expected output - it would have been `2018020`.  Maybe it would have been easier for you to figure out why the output wasn't expected;  I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reserved space to store exactly 8 `char`s:

```
char date[8];
```

To store the date properly `20180202` you need

```
char date[9];
```

because `sprintf()` puts the extra `'\0'` character to the buffer you pass for proper c-style string termination.

I'd suspect you declared your buffers like

```
char buffer[???];
char date[8];
```

since these are most likely stored on your processors stack, you need to read that backwards, thus the output placed at `buffer` overwrites that terminating `'\0'`, and appears immediately after `date`.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely you declared two arrays and they are lined up in a way that allowed for the `buf` to overwrite the null terminator of `date` and thus it's "*concatenating*" the two.

I can't write code to reproduce this because it's undefined behavior and thus not reliable. But I can tell you how you can avoid it,

```
snprintf(date, sizeof(date), "%d%02d%02d", Time.year(), Time.month(), Time.day());
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "{\"team\":\"%s\"}", team.c_str());
```

Having said that, why are you using `snprintf()` when this appears to be c++? And so there are more suitable solutions for this kind of problem.

This would print an incorrect value, but would not cause any *unexpected* behavior.

Strings in c are simply arrays with a special arrangement. If the string has *n* printable characters it should be stored in an array of size *n + 1*, so that you can add what is called a *null* terminator. It's a special value that indicates the *end* of the string.

Your second `snprintf()` is overwriting such *null* terminator of the `date` array and thus appearing to concatenate both strings.